# Where calculating RippleDrawable radius wtih RADIUS_AUTO

Tags: android, rippledrawable

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable#RADIUS_AUTO) says `Radius value that specifies the ripple radius should be computed based on the size of the ripple's container.` but i can't find exactly where it calculating. I tried to fugire it out with debugger but unsuccesful.

Can you tell me where this calculation take place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. That calculation perform in `setup(float, int)` method of `RippleComponent` class:

```
public final void setup(float maxRadius, int densityDpi) {
    if (maxRadius >= 0) {
        mHasMaxRadius = true;
        mTargetRadius = maxRadius;
    } else {
        mTargetRadius = getTargetRadius(mBounds); // this place!
    }

    mDensityScale = densityDpi * DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT_SCALE;

    onTargetRadiusChanged(mTargetRadius);
}
```

Exactly this class handles size and positioning common to the ripple & focus states. Neither `RippleState` nor `RippleDrawable`.